# How to stop the Find if Then function from cutting/deleting/pasting rows that were already cut/deleted/pasted in same sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I adapted below code so that entire rows are cut and pasted at a lower location in SAME sheet based on specific value in a column. The rows are pasted not in last row, but in a few empty rows in between rows that have data. Let's say I have 12 rows that need to be copied and pasted in the 12 empty rows in between the data. The below code will first move the rows to the 12 empty rows but it will then continue to move about 6 rows that have already been moved to a location at the end of all rows. How can I have the code stop once it moves the 12 rows?

```
Sub MoveLS()

    Dim i As Variant
    Dim endrow As Integer
    Dim Version3 As Worksheet

    Set Version3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Version 3")

    endrow = Version3.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row

    For i = 2 To endrow
        If Version3.Cells(i, "AVI").Value = "3. NOT ON LIST" Then
            Version3.Cells(i, "AVI").EntireRow.Cut Destination:=Version3.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            Version3.Cells(i, "AVI").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Run a `COUNTIF()` to see how many rows you need to move, then stop looping once you've moved that many rows.

Comment: Thanks...I'm new to VBA so would not know where to place this.....I managed a to get what I needed through a workaround...in the row (just above the row where the 12 empty rows in between data start), in column AVI, I placed an #NA (like the one you get when vlookup does not return anything), so then the VBA code encounters an error and stops working....but by then the 12 rows were copied, deleted and pasted in the 12 empty rows where I wanted them...

Comment: Thanks. I changed Cut to Copy and it copied and pasted all the 12 rows in the correct rows (ie the 12 blank rows in between the other rows that have data) - but then it cut the 1st (of the 12) copied rows and pasted at the very bottom of the sheet. Is there anyway, I can make it stay once it is pasted (ie in the 12 rows) rather than have it cut and pasted again (at the very end of sheet)?

Comment: Remove the offset from your endRow calculation - that takes you one row too far

Comment: Perfect - it worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach: hold off deleting the rows until you're finished with the loop.

```
Sub MoveLS()

    Dim i As Variant
    Dim endrow As Integer
    Dim Version3 As Worksheet
    Dim rngDel As Range

    Set Version3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Version 3")

    endrow = Version3.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'removed the Offset(1, 0)
    For i = 2 To endrow
        If Version3.Cells(i, "AVI").Value = "3. NOT ON LIST" Then

            Version3.Cells(i, "AVI").EntireRow.Cut _
                    Destination:=Version3.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            'add a dummy value so the next xlDown doesn't stop here
            Version3.Cells(i, "A").Value = "XXX" 

            'build range to delete later
            If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDel = Version3.Cells(i, "AVI")
            Else
                Set rngDel = Application.Union(rngDel, Version3.Cells(i, "AVI"))
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'delete any cleared rows
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot the first cut row would now be empty so your xlDown would hit that and stop...   You can either insert a dummy value as above, or change the `Cut` to a `Copy`

Comment: Thanks - I ran above code and the following happened: Out of the 12 Rows that needed to be moved to the empty rows in between the data....1 Row was moved Down by 1 Row only (so not in the empty rows in between data) and the other 11 rows were deleted but were not pasted anywhere